# Appending all files in a directory to one document

Tags: php

How can I get all the files in my directory on php and put them in one document called "combined.txt"
I had this code before:

```
file_put_contents("combined.txt", ""); // Empty the file first
foreach ($files as $my_file) {
file_put_contents("combined.txt", $my_file, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

But I get this **error:**

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /script2.php on
>   line 177

I think its because I didn't delceare which files, I just have this code before it:

```
$directory_with_files = './'.date('m-d-Y');
$dh  = opendir($directory_with_files);
$files = array();
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)))
{
    if(in_array($filename, array('.', '..')) || is_dir($filename))
        continue;

    $files[] = $filename;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: write files to `$files` and read from `$new_files`??

Comment: use scandir($path);

Comment: You're trying to iterate through `$new_files`, but I don't see it getting defined anywhere?

Comment: Oh I forgot to paste that part, $new_files are the variables of files that I editted before, but it didnt work. I tried changing it to $files, but it also didnt work

Comment: Whats that for? And where am I suppose to put it? @jothi

Comment: try using glob and read all files and merge the contents of all files

Comment: Update your code to what it actually is. No _"I forgot to paste that part..."_. If you want our help, **give us the exact code**. We can't sit here and guess!

Comment: I did if you look more closely, you would see it @MagnusEriksson

Comment: `foreach ($files $my_file)`. You forgot the `as`: `foreach ($files as $my_file)`

Comment: Done, thanks @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this by using scandir() function

```
$directory_with_files    = './'.date('m-d-Y');
$files = scandir($directory_with_files);
$valid_extension=array('txt','php','inc')// make a list of valid extention
foreach($files as $file)
{
  $ext=explode('.',$file);
  $ext=strtolower(array_pop($ext))
  if(in_array($ext,$valid_extension))
  {
     include_once($directory_with_files."/".$file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer, dont forget to upvote also